# How do I Find all items that aren't a certain type

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my collection, I need to remove any items that aren't a specific type.

```
$result = $db.configs.find(
            array('$not' =>  array(
                    array('$or' => array(
                            array('_id' => array('$type' => 2)),
                            array('_id' => array('$type' => 7)),
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

If i remove the '$not' wrapper around the element, it does find all the elements that ARE type 2 and 7, am I using Not incorrectly?

Comment: Which collection? There's an array_filter() function that may be useful?

Comment: the collection is called 'configs', not really sure if that's relevant to the question though? @Luke

Comment: It depends on type of your `_id`. If it is `objectId`, query will return empty cursor as you are filtering by `7` and `2` which are `objectId` and `string` respectively. Also it will be better if you provide sample document?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and)** operator with a combination of **[`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not)** expressions. The following mongo shell demonstration shows how you can test the query you should use:

```
use test
db.test.insert([
    {"_id": 1, a: 1},
    {"_id": new Date(), a: 2 },
    {"_id": "foo", a: 3},
    {"_id": ObjectId("5579621f3cab061ff5c618c7"), a: 4}    
])

db.test.find({
    "$and":[ 
        { "_id": { "$not": { "$type": 7 } } },
        { "_id": { "$not": { "$type": 2 } } }
    ]
})
```

**Result**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "a" : 1
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2015-06-24T09:59:54.230Z"),
    "a" : 2
}
```

Equivalent PHP mongo query:

```
$result = $db.test.find(
    array('$and' =>  array(
            array('_id' => array(
                array("$not" => array('$type' => 2))
            ),
            array('_id' => array(
                array("$not" => array('$type' => 7))
            )
        )
    )
);
```